# neo4j HA healthcheck end-points return 401 through AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I'm running a 4 node (2 cluster nodes, 2 arbiter nodes) neo4j 2.2.5 enterprise cluster on 2 virtual machines in a private subnet within AWS EC2 (Linux). I'm able to start the clusters and have members join them. 
I have also configured an AWD Elastic Load Balancer to access the 7474 port of the different machines.  The load balancer health check is configured with the end point below.

```
      /db/manage/server/ha/available
```

However, the servers return a 401 unauthorized as they don't contain an authorization header.  I'm not sure if AWS allows you to pass auth values for healthcheck. Is it possible to have neo4j NOT require auth for "just" these health check URLs? (i don't want to disable auth for the entire db).
Thx,
NN

Answer (score 3):

AWS ELB doesn't support custom header, I suggest to you use HAproxy instead of ELB - Here is the great description of the configuration - http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/08/neo4j-and-haproxy-some-best-practices-and-tricks/

Answer (score 3):

The following is available in 2.3.3:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-configuration.html#config_dbms.security.ha_status_auth_enabled

dbms.security.ha_status_auth_enabled

**Description**: Require authorization for access to the HA status endpoints.

**Valid values**: dbms.security.ha_status_auth_enabled is a boolean.

**Default value**: true

Changing that to false will allow the HA status check endpoint to be accessible without security.  I'm currently using this as a means to use AWS ELB with Neo4j and it's working just fine.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! This should be the accepted answer to this question. EDIT: just noticed the version constraint the OP had.. anyway this is useful for those running the latest 2.x

Answer (score 1):

you need to set these two variables to the **false** in neo4j.conf default value of these two variables is **true**.

These variables help ELB for health check without authentication

```
dbms.security.ha_status_auth_enabled=false
dbms.security.causal_clustering_status_auth_enabled=false
```

for setting up elastic load balancer

1. Following listeners need to be configured for the load balancer[image: Listeners in load balancer]
2. Set up two elastic load balancer. One for reading and is used in neo4j desktop and other is used for writing the data to neo4j

For status endpoint please check the URL according to Neo4j version - 
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/causal-cluster/http-endpoints/

ELB for reading data.

Health check - http:7474/db/manage/server/causalclustering/available
[image]

ELB for writing data.

Health check - http:7474/db/manage/server/causalclustering/writable
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question - there is no possibility to suppress authentication for just one path in Neo4j. As we see [there](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/AbstractNeoServer.java#L115) - whitelist is hardcoded and can't be extended.

---

Maybe you can use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as reverse proxy in your case?

Solution:

- place nginx in front of Neo4j instance.
- configure standard proxy setup
- for `/db/manage/server/ha/available` automatically add authorization headers

There is couple of articles to help you with setup:

- [NGINX REVERSE PROXY](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) by Nginx
- [Understanding Nginx HTTP Proxying, Load Balancing, Buffering, and Caching](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching)

Example (not tested):

```
location /db/manage/server/ha/available {
    proxy_set_header HOST "Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==";

    proxy_pass http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/ha/available;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I really like it. I tried it but unfortunately neo4j does not seem to like that auth header. it says bad header in the response

Comment: I am not sure how exactly Auth header should be passed there. Also, check that you are sending correct encrypted password.

Answer (score 0):

Actually FylmTM's solution is the right approach! This just needs some minor tweaks - pl see below..

```
location /db/manage/server/ha/available {
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==";
proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
proxy_pass http://ip-10-0-1-98:7474/db/manage/server/ha/available;
```

}

This addresses the above issue and you can use your AWS ELB for healthchecks!
Now I still need to figure out why I'm getting a 404 error on these urls (pl see this post below)

[neo4j HA cluster end points return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764529/neo4j-ha-cluster-end-points-return-404)