# neo4j HA cluster end points return 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I'm running a 4 node (2 cluster nodes, 2 arbiter nodes) neo4j 2.2.5 enterprise cluster on 2 virtual machines in a private subnet within AWS EC2 (Linux). I'm able to start the clusters and have members join them. However, when I try to access the health check URLs even on the local machine, I receive a 404 error. I may have missed something very basic here and would appreciate any pointers.
The same thing works fine on my local machine. Also, on the server the system takes about 2 minutes to become available while on my local it comes up in seconds.

```
        curl -v  http://ip-10-0-1-98:7474/db/manage/server/ha/available

        [ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-98 log]$ curl -v  http://ip-10-0-1-98:7474/db/manage/server/ha/available
        *   Trying 10.0.1.98...
        * Connected to ip-10-0-1-98 (10.0.1.98) port 7474 (#0)
        > GET /db/manage/server/ha/available HTTP/1.1
        > User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
        > Host: ip-10-0-1-98:7474
        > Accept: */*
        > 
       < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
       < Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 13:06:52 GMT
       < Content-Type: text/plain
       < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
       < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
       < Server: Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103)
       < 
       * Connection #0 to host ip-10-0-1-98 left intact
```

Also, in the configuration above I have disabled dbms auth and so am not passing the credentials.
Thx,
Neo-Newbie!

Comment: Does your security group configured properly?

Comment: yes. this is called from the same machine..and as you can see the connection is established, only the url is not found..

Comment: Please share you neo4j-server.properties with us from all machines

Answer (score 0):

Btw, this turned out to be due to a misconfiguration in neo4j.properties file. There was an extra colon in the server:port specification for this line..

```
      ha.server=ip-10-0-2-98::6001
```